# Convert a list of pandas series with the same index into a dictionary

Tags: pandas, list, series

I have a list of pandas Series, each having the same index. I want to convert this list into a dictionary, where the keys are the index values (which is the same across all Series, and values is a list of values in the Series objects). Here is an example:

```
series_1:
A 1
B 2
C 3

series_2:
A 11
B 22
C 33
```

What is the most efficient (ideally no loops) way to convert `[series_1, series_2]` into `{'A': [1,11], 'B': [2,22], 'C': [3,33]}`? I need an efficient way because the number of series I have is 10K each having 20K elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way `concat` then `groupby`

```
pd.concat([s1,s2]).groupby(level=0).apply(list).to_dict()
Out[375]: {'A': [1, 11], 'B': [2, 22], 'C': [3, 33]}
```

---

Update

```
pd.concat([s1,s2],axis=1).T.to_dict('l')
Out[379]: {'A': [1, 11], 'B': [2, 22], 'C': [3, 33]}
```

Comment: Thank you. Please see my edits in the question for the reason why I need efficiency. For 1000 series each having 20K elements, your method takes 8 seconds while a nested loop over the lists and index takes 5 seconds. I need a more efficient method.

Comment: The updated version takes 2.5 seconds for the same setting, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best performance is converting to dictionary of numpy arrays instead of dictionary of lists and using the `np.array` of the series to construct dictionary.

Besides, if you really need dictionary of lists, using `dict` and `zip` on `s.index` and `np.array.tolist()` is still much better than 2 methods above. 2 methods above have overhead of creating dataframe.

**Setup**: *a series of 20k numbers*

```
s = pd.Series(np.arange(20000))
```

**Create dictionary of `np.array` on 1000 series**

```
dict(zip(s.index, np.column_stack([s.values]*1000)))
```

**Create dictionary of `list` on 1000 series**

```
dict(zip(s.index, np.column_stack([s.values]*1000).tolist()))
```

Timing all 4 methods:

```
In [1071]: %timeit dict(zip(s.index, np.column_stack([s.values]*1000)))
195 ms ± 879 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [1072]:  %timeit dict(zip(s.index, np.column_stack([s.values]*1000).tolist()))
1.05 s ± 4.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [1075]: %timeit pd.concat([s]*1000).groupby(level=0).apply(list).to_dict()
7.01 s ± 70.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [1077]: %timeit pd.concat([s]*1000, axis=1).T.to_dict('l')
2.83 s ± 11.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Using `numpy` array of series with `dict` and `zip` is much faster than both methods using `pd.concat`. Dictionary of `np.array` is the fastest at `195 ms` over 5 times faster the next one.